# mongodb this db does not have sharding enabled even though i did connect to mongos

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to addshard via router to 2 replication set on windows. I already searched a lot of similar questions and tried the same steps. But unfornately ... Below is my steps:
for config node, config file:

```
dbpath=D:/MongoDBConfigNode/config
logpath=D:/MongoDBConfigNode/logs/config1.log
logappend=true
bind_ip=0.0.0.0
port = 17011
configsvr=true
replSet=configsvr
```

starting using `mongod -f D:\MongoDBConfigNode\config-17011.conf` and connect to it using `mongo -host 127.0.0.1 --port 17011` and initialize:

```
  config = {   _id : "configsvr", members :[{_id : 0, host : "127.0.0.1:17011" }]}
{
        "_id" : "configsvr",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:17011"
                }
        ]
}
> rs.initiate(config)
{
        "ok" : 1,
        "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(1622598318, 1),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")
        },
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0)
}
```

I have two replication set, sharding1 and sharding2, each has 3 servers in it.

port 37018 config file, 37017 and 37019 are similar

```
 dbpath=D:\MongoDBSharding1Slave1\data
    bind_ip=0.0.0.0
    port=37018
    logpath=D:\MongoDBSharding1Slave1\logs\sharding1Slave1.log
    replSet=Sharding1
    shardsvr=true
```

I started mongodb on port 37017, 37018, 37019 like following:

```
mongod -f D:\MongoDBSharding1Master\config\mongo_37017.conf
mongod -f D:\MongoDBSharding1Slave1\config\mongo_37018.conf
mongod -f D:\MongoDBSharding1Slave2\config\mongo_37019.conf
```

using following to connect `mongo --port 37017`, and intialize like following:

```
   config = { _id : "Sharding1", members : [{_id : 0, host : "127.0.0.1:37017"},{_id : 1, host : "127.0.0.1:37018"},{_id : 2, host : "127.0.0.1:37019", "arbiterOnly":true }]}
{
        "_id" : "Sharding1",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:37017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:37018"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:37019",
                        "arbiterOnly" : true
                }
        ]
}
> rs.initiate(config);
```

I did the same for Sharding2. Then i started the router node:
router node config:

```
port=27017
bind_ip=0.0.0.0
logpath=D:/MongoDBRoute/logs/route.log
configdb=configsvr/localhost:17011
```

started the node like this:

```
mongos -f D:\MongoDBRoute\config\route-27017.conf
```

connect to it like this:

mongo --host localhost --port 27017,

and i got the erros :

```
> sh.status()
printShardingStatus: this db does not have sharding enabled. be sure you are connecting to a mongos from the shell and not to a mongod.
> sh.addShard("Sharding1/127.0.0.1:37017, 127.0.0.1:37018, 127.0.0.1:37019");
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no such command: 'addShard'",
        "code" : 59,
        "codeName" : "CommandNotFound"
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.enableSharding/

Comment: Also, refer this for detailed steps: [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/). Verify yourself if you have followed all the steps described in the linked documentation.

Comment: The config file is not valid YAML format. Apart from that your config looks quite OK from first view. What do you get from `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand("getShardMap").map`?

Comment: You mixed `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`. I don't know whether it makes any difference, but try to use only either of them.

Comment: Review the ports in your config files. Perhaps you did a typo on it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit hi, for db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand("getShardMap").map, nothing prints out here.

Comment: @D.SM > sh.enableSharding('lg_resume')
uncaught exception: Error: not connected to a mongos :
sh._checkMongos@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:8:15
sh._adminCommand@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:18:9
sh.enableSharding@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:114:12
@(shell):1:1, even though i started the port 27017 with mongos...

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit hmm, let me change to yaml config and review again

Comment: Did the `mongos` start? Perhaps you have already a `mongod` running on port 27017 (maybe installed as a service)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit wow , you are correct, sth is running on 27017 by my company(i cant kill it), i changed the port to 27018 for mongs and sh.status() works. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your service manager `services.msc`, there you should be able to stop it.

or use

```
sc stop <SERVICE_NAME>
sc delete <SERVICE_NAME>
```

If the service does not stop, try

```
sc queryex <SERVICE_NAME>
taskkill /pid <SERVICE_PID> /f
```

If the service is started with config files (like the ones you defined) you can remove it also like this:

```
mongod.exe -f D:\MongoDBConfig\config-27017.conf --remove
```

Comment: hi, any hint would be appreciate. sh.addShard("Sharding1/127.0.0.1:37017, 127.0.0.1:37018, 127.0.0.1:37019") gave following error(I already changed configdb=configsvr/localhost:17011 to configdb=configsvr/127.0.0.01:17011)        "errmsg" : "Can't use localhost as a shard since all shards need to communicate. Either use all shards and configdbs in localhost or all in actual IPs. host:  127.0.0.1:37018 isLocalHost:0",  "code" : 72, "codeName" : "InvalidOptions",

Comment: also db.hostInfo() on mongos gives me  "hostname" : "xxxx-LuL:27018",

Comment: it turns out my sharding1 doesnt have a master, feels its working now thank you!